# Team Foundation Server 2017 new Work Item Look and Feel not "there"

Tags: team-foundation-server

We've installed TFS 2017 as an on-premise installation and this document [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/new-work-item-experience) states:

> **Feature availability**: The new form and its corresponding features are
>   available from Team Services and the web portal for TFS 2017. The
>   switch to the new form is automatic for all user accounts.

And as a reference new bugs etc should be displayed like this:

[image: new WIT]

But they are not. I see new features in my tickets but the new work item type design is missing.

I've also created an entire new project as I was hoping that new projects receive the new work item type templates, but they don't, as displayed here:

[image: old one]

Any hints on that are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to be clear on that: the new form is not automatically enabled nor is the feature available out of the box for a standard user.

To be able to do anything with the new form, an admin must enable it for the collection:

- **Hover** over the settings icon and select "Collection Settings" (if you click on the settings icon, you won't see it)
- To the left click onto "Enable the new work item form"

After you've done it, open a work item, you will see a "try the new form" link on the top right corner. Clicking on this renders the new form.

But if you think that's all, you are wrong.
The "try the new form" are available only for admins per default, that's why you see, your admin colleague see it, but your users won't.

- Go to the Collection settings again (hover)
- To the left click on "Configure the opt-in model" and set it to either *Enable opt-in for all users* or *New form only*

The *Enable opt-in for all users* option allows the users to switch forth and back between the layouts.

So that's the "the switch to the new form is automatic for all user accounts." part ...